# Suppress warning of rbenv versions if no rubies installed

Tags: grep, console, stdout, stderr

At the moment I'm working on Ansible role that installs `ruby` with `rbenv`. In order not to install same `ruby` version every time I run setup task I have to check that no needed `ruby` is already installed.

However, I have two cases:

1) when no `ruby` installed at all;

2) when some `ruby` versions already present.

For that purpose I use `rbenv versions | grep {{ needed_ruby_version }}`.

If system has at least one ruby version installed - everything is OK.

However, if there is no `ruby` at all - command `rbenv versions | grep {{ needed_ruby_version }}` returns `Warning: no Ruby detected on the system`, so that pipe and `grep` does nothing any more.

Is it possible to somehow modify this command and prevent this warning (or suppress it) and pass output to `grep`?